# which camo for snowy maps?

Tags: battlefield-3

On most maps I've been using mostly spec ops black, but it makes no sense at all on snow.

As far as I can see, there is no dedicated snow camo.

Which would be the best camo for snowy maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RU Urban or US Premium 4(Blue/White Urban digital)seem to be the best, some actual snow camo would be nice though.

Comment: Right, haven't tried Navy Blue Digital, as you have to do "Dedicated" assignment first. How about SPECACT for RU?

Comment: vartec, that camo would be plausible if it didn't have the black body armour parts in it. I think that makes it overall a bit to dark.